Некорректная работа пользовательского поля (Клиент) CRM
некорректно работает с объекте Сделка пользовательское поле, тип которого = Привязка к элементам CRM -> Контакт (Клиент) : при работе в форме невозможно выбрать все контакты (предоставлен выбор только одного контакта)
